# SCfigure fly around

Tags: floats

I've used the `SCfigure` environment to make a side caption. The caption/comment works very well, but the picture is not located where I want it to be. For example, I would like to dock the following picture below the subtitle (4.4.3.....)

[image]

Here is the code

```
\subsubsection*{4.4.3 Variance-covariance propagation: some examples}
\begin{SCfigure}[\sidecaptionrelwidth][!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{E:/CloudStore/Dropbox/3SM/AdjOne/PicSet/4_43a.jpg}
\caption{\minibox{Angles $\alpha$ $\&$ $\beta$ have been measured with \\ standard deviation of $s_\alpha=s_\beta=1$ mgon \\
\\ Compute the Standard Deviation $S_\gamma$}}
\end{SCfigure}
```

Cheers
SL

Comment: It's a float, so it floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `SCfigure` defines a float object, it will float according to the algorithms implemented in LaTeX. You can try to restrict the positioning using the second optional argument (as you are already doing), but this won't force LaTeX to place the figure exactly where you want in all the cases.

In the code below I show one option; I also made some changes to your code: no need to use a `minipage` to typeset the narrow caption (besides, you were nor using the right syntax for `minipage`; it's an environment with a mandatory argument (the width)); instead, use the `raggedright` option for `sidecap`, so narrow side captions will be automatically ragged.

Also, why are you numbering your subsections by hand? Let LaTeX do the automatic numbering for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[raggedright]{sidecap}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\subsubsection{Variance-covariance propagation: some examples}
\begin{SCfigure}[\sidecaptionrelwidth][!hb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Angles $\alpha$ $\&$ $\beta$ have been measured with standard deviation of $s_\alpha=s_\beta=1$ mgon Compute the Standard Deviation $S_\gamma$}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to place the figure exactly where it appears in the code, switch to the powerful [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package that allows you to use the H placement float specifier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\subsubsection{Variance-covariance propagation: some examples}

\thisfloatsetup{
  capposition=beside,
  capbesideposition={bottom,right},
  capbesidewidth=.3\textwidth,
  justification=raggedright
}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \floatbox{figure}[\FBwidth]{\caption{Angles $\alpha$ $\&$ $\beta$ have been measured with standard deviation of $s_\alpha=s_\beta=1$ mgon Compute the Standard Deviation $S_\gamma$}
}{\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Notice that, in general, it's bettwe to use the `width` and/or `height` options for `\includegraphics` than `scale`.

[image]